# CodeIgniter - Calling function from function

Tags: php, codeigniter, visibility

I have a problem. I have a basic structure like this.

> /model/function (admin/cat)

But what I need is to call another function from that 'cat', I know how to call another function, but I want my URL to look like this then.

> /model/function1/function2
>   (admin/cat/add || admin/cat/delete
>   etc...)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use routing or create a 'cat' controller in an 'admin' folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the name of the function as an argument to your `cat` function, like this

```
function cat($func=''){
    //call the function passed as an argument
    if ($func && function_exists($func))
        $this->$func();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure what the model has to do this with...

But I think what you're asking is you want a url structure like

/admin/cat/param

then your Controller should look like this

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    function cat($passed_in_param1)
    {
        if ($passed_in_param1 == 'add') {
            // add a new category here
        }
        elseif ($passed_in_param1 == 'del') {
            // del category here 
        }

    }
}
?>
```